# Securely allowing .zips and PDF in my upload script

Tags: php, file-upload

I am currently building a feature to allow my users to upload documents to send to other users on my website.

Now I understand some risks that can happen with images that allow users to upload an image that contains PHP code that will be executed.

I have researched online prior to posting this question and while looking at the PHP docs regarding MIME type verification and found this

```
$_FILES['userfile']['type']
  This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore 
  don't take its value for granted.
```

Before hand I thought this would be the main method I would be using to fight against bad files being uploaded, although my efforts to find a way to upload safely all point towards checking the MIME type as above.

Ideally I would like the users to be able to upload txt, pdf, doc and ZIP files.

Is the above method ( of checking MIME type ) still a viable option to use?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I check the original filename.  I also rename the uploaded file using the extensions I want.  So if someone uploads an .exe file, there are two hurdles:

1. I have checked the filename, seen the .exe and denied the upload
2. I have renamed all files to my own set of possible extensions and .exe isn't one of them.

Zips are ugly because they can contain bad files, so they need to be unzipped and each file checked and renamed and any bad files deleted.

S

Comment: I will let the user know that it is their responsibility to open files safely and run their own security measures regarding zips, as that is something out of my control because I will not be opening zips and scanning every file inside. Do you have the script you use to check the file names correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will be useful.

```
private function file_contains_php($file) {
        $contents = file_get_contents($file);
        $position = strpos($contents, '<?php');
        return $position !== false;
}
```